# Find out output of c-program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void compute(int);
int cube(int);
int main( )
{
        compute(3);
}
void compute(int in)
{
        int res=0,i;
        for(i=1;i<=in;i++);
        {
                res=cube(i);
                printf("%d %d",res,i);
        }
}
int cube(int n)
{
        return (n*n*n);
}
```

~
output :  64 4

How does it happen ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Semicolon at the end of your `for` line.

Comment: Right.  The code block after the `for` loop is only executed once.

Answer (score 6):

Due to a semicolon on your `for` line, the statement increments i until it is not <= 3, which is 4.  Then the code below it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C99, you may want to get into the habit of declaring the variable controlling a for loop inside the for statement itself.

```
    for (int i=1; i<=in; i++);
    {
        /* i is not in scope here */
    }
```

*And, now that I've written that, the idiomatic way to write a loop is to start at `0` and test with `<`*

```
    for (int i=0; i<in; i++);
    {
        /* i is not in scope here */
    }
```